# What is the main difference between onTap and onChanged function?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was using DropDownItem widget in flutter, was preferring it through a tutorial series. But didn't really understand the basic difference between onTap and onChanged function as it feels both functions have the same logic and even executed at the same exact time

I tried to print a string on onChanged function, which worked. But I tried to do the same with onTap but it didn't go as planned. I just couldn't understand the basic difference between them. Does the UI change while using onTap function? I've never noticed something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Theres an explanation in `DropdownButton` Flutter documentation, `onTap` triggered when called when the user selects an item, where `onChanged` triggered when called when the dropdown button is tapped. It's different things between select an item (in dropdown) and tap a dropdown (its like only click the dropdown).

You can see full documentation in here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html

`onTap` function is same as `onPressed` in `TextButton`.